# Python multiprocessing on directory files with shared counter

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm new to Python and writing a script which receives a single directory name argument, and returns a list of all the files in said directory along with their MD5HASH, recursively.

The script utilizes multiprocessing for more efficiency.

I'd like the output to look like this: "FileCounter, FileName, MD5HASH..."

The only part that doesn't seem to work is the counter - Despite the fact I'm using Value lock as suggested by some posts here, the order still gets scrambled from time to time (i.e. 1,2,3,6,4,6 instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6).

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from multiprocessing import Pool,Value
import sys
import os
import hashlib
from time import sleep

counter = Value('i',0)

def md5gen (filePath):
        global counter
        with counter.get_lock():
                counter.value += 1
        print str(counter.value)+","+filePath+","+hashlib.md5(filePath).hexdigest()

# Check argument
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print "No folder specified!"
        quit()

folderName = sys.argv[1]
if not os.path.exists(folderName):
        print "Not a valid folder!"
        quit()

fileNames = []
for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(folderName):
        for file in files:
                filePath = subdir + os.sep + file
                fileNames.append(filePath)

p = Pool()
p.map(md5gen,fileNames)
```

Would really like to know what I'm doing wrong here.
Thank you!

Comment: You do know that your code is getting the hash of the file path and not of the contents of the file, right?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Yes, it's on purpose. Content may be empty, I'm only interested in the file path.

Comment: Multiprocessing does not garantee that each subprocess will return in the same order they were started.  You could maybe collect the output, sort it then print out your results?